# Libtorch: The U-net segmentation output is correct, but repeated 3 times beside each other

Tags: c++, opencv, image-segmentation, libtorch, unet-neural-network

I’m trying to deploy the model at [this link](https://github.com/khanhha/crack_segmentation) in a C++ crack segmentation application. I followed the steps at [this link](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_export.html) for converting the PyTorch model and serializing it. [Here is a link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qWYe5ThH8KSMQP3EZ3hqiCrWbc_Si1HA/view?usp=sharing) to the traced module. Also, [this is a link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GCEKqNxqtbksunOTYxYMpjAtqbNxDUp0/view?usp=sharing) to a sample image.

Here is the code at the original ‘inference_unet.py’ file:

```
import sys
import os
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
import cv2 as cv
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from unet.unet_transfer import UNet16, input_size
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import argparse
from os.path import join
from PIL import Image
import gc
from utils import load_unet_vgg16, load_unet_resnet_101, load_unet_resnet_34
from tqdm import tqdm

import torch #Hedeya
import torchvision #Hedeya

def evaluate_img(model, img):
    input_width, input_height = input_size[0], input_size[1]
    
    img_1 = cv.resize(img, (input_width, input_height), cv.INTER_AREA)
    print(img_1.shape)
    #X = train_tfms(Image.fromarray(img_1))
    X = train_tfms(img_1)
    print(X.shape)
    X = Variable(X.unsqueeze(0)).cuda()  # [N, 1, H, W]
    print(X.shape)
    
    # Use torch.jit.trace to generate a torch.jit.ScriptModule via tracing [Hedeya]
    traced_script_module = torch.jit.trace(model, X) #Hedeya
    traced_script_module.save("traced_unet-vgg16_model.pt") #Hedeya
    
    mask = model(X)
    print(mask.shape)
    #mask = F.sigmoid(mask[0, 0]).data.cpu().numpy()
    print(mask[0,0].shape)
    mask = torch.sigmoid(mask[0, 0]).data.cpu().numpy() #Hedeya
    mask = cv.resize(mask, (img_width, img_height), cv.INTER_AREA)
    return mask

def evaluate_img_patch(model, img):
    input_width, input_height = input_size[0], input_size[1]

    img_height, img_width, img_channels = img.shape

    if img_width < input_width or img_height < input_height:
        return evaluate_img(model, img)

    stride_ratio = 0.1
    stride = int(input_width * stride_ratio)

    normalization_map = np.zeros((img_height, img_width), dtype=np.int16)

    patches = []
    patch_locs = []
    for y in range(0, img_height - input_height + 1, stride):
        for x in range(0, img_width - input_width + 1, stride):
            segment = img[y:y + input_height, x:x + input_width]
            normalization_map[y:y + input_height, x:x + input_width] += 1
            patches.append(segment)
            patch_locs.append((x, y))

    patches = np.array(patches)
    if len(patch_locs) <= 0:
        return None

    preds = []
    for i, patch in enumerate(patches):
        patch_n = train_tfms(Image.fromarray(patch))
        X = Variable(patch_n.unsqueeze(0)).cuda()  # [N, 1, H, W]
        masks_pred = model(X)
        #mask = F.sigmoid(masks_pred[0, 0]).data.cpu().numpy()
        mask = torch.sigmoid(masks_pred[0, 0]).data.cpu().numpy() #Hedeya
        preds.append(mask)

    probability_map = np.zeros((img_height, img_width), dtype=float)
    for i, response in enumerate(preds):
        coords = patch_locs[i]
        probability_map[coords[1]:coords[1] + input_height, coords[0]:coords[0] + input_width] += response

    return probability_map

def disable_axis():
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.gca().axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    plt.gca().axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    plt.gca().axes.get_xaxis().set_ticklabels([])
    plt.gca().axes.get_yaxis().set_ticklabels([])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-img_dir',type=str, help='input dataset directory')
    parser.add_argument('-model_path', type=str, help='trained model path')
    parser.add_argument('-model_type', type=str, choices=['vgg16', 'resnet101', 'resnet34'])
    parser.add_argument('-out_viz_dir', type=str, default='', required=False, help='visualization output dir')
    parser.add_argument('-out_pred_dir', type=str, default='', required=False,  help='prediction output dir')
    parser.add_argument('-threshold', type=float, default=0.2 , help='threshold to cut off crack response')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.out_viz_dir != '':
        os.makedirs(args.out_viz_dir, exist_ok=True)
        for path in Path(args.out_viz_dir).glob('*.*'):
            os.remove(str(path))

    if args.out_pred_dir != '':
        os.makedirs(args.out_pred_dir, exist_ok=True)
        for path in Path(args.out_pred_dir).glob('*.*'):
            os.remove(str(path))

    if args.model_type == 'vgg16':
        #model = load_unet_vgg16(args.model_path)
        model = load_unet_vgg16(args.model_path, None) #Hedeya + None I/O False
    elif args.model_type  == 'resnet101':
        model = load_unet_resnet_101(args.model_path)
    elif args.model_type  == 'resnet34':
        model = load_unet_resnet_34(args.model_path)
        print(model)
    else:
        print('undefind model name pattern')
        exit()

    channel_means = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]
    channel_stds  = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]

    paths = [path for path in Path(args.img_dir).glob('*.*')]
    for path in tqdm(paths):
        #print(str(path))

        train_tfms = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize(channel_means, channel_stds)])

        img_0 = Image.open(str(path))
        img_0 = np.asarray(img_0)
        if len(img_0.shape) != 3:
            print(f'incorrect image shape: {path.name}{img_0.shape}')
            continue

        img_0 = img_0[:,:,:3]

        img_height, img_width, img_channels = img_0.shape

        prob_map_full = evaluate_img(model, img_0)

        if args.out_pred_dir != '':
            cv.imwrite(filename=join(args.out_pred_dir, f'{path.stem}.jpg'), img=(prob_map_full * 255).astype(np.uint8))

        if args.out_viz_dir != '':
            # plt.subplot(121)
            # plt.imshow(img_0), plt.title(f'{img_0.shape}')
            if img_0.shape[0] > 2000 or img_0.shape[1] > 2000:
                img_1 = cv.resize(img_0, None, fx=0.2, fy=0.2, interpolation=cv.INTER_AREA)
            else:
                img_1 = img_0

            # plt.subplot(122)
            # plt.imshow(img_0), plt.title(f'{img_0.shape}')
            # plt.show()

            prob_map_patch = evaluate_img_patch(model, img_1)

            #plt.title(f'name={path.stem}. \n cut-off threshold = {args.threshold}', fontsize=4)
            prob_map_viz_patch = prob_map_patch.copy()
            prob_map_viz_patch = prob_map_viz_patch/ prob_map_viz_patch.max()
            prob_map_viz_patch[prob_map_viz_patch < args.threshold] = 0.0
            fig = plt.figure()
            st = fig.suptitle(f'name={path.stem} \n cut-off threshold = {args.threshold}', fontsize="x-large")
            ax = fig.add_subplot(231)
            ax.imshow(img_1)
            ax = fig.add_subplot(232)
            ax.imshow(prob_map_viz_patch)
            ax = fig.add_subplot(233)
            ax.imshow(img_1)
            ax.imshow(prob_map_viz_patch, alpha=0.4)

            prob_map_viz_full = prob_map_full.copy()
            prob_map_viz_full[prob_map_viz_full < args.threshold] = 0.0

            ax = fig.add_subplot(234)
            ax.imshow(img_0)
            ax = fig.add_subplot(235)
            ax.imshow(prob_map_viz_full)
            ax = fig.add_subplot(236)
            ax.imshow(img_0)
            ax.imshow(prob_map_viz_full, alpha=0.4)

            plt.savefig(join(args.out_viz_dir, f'{path.stem}.jpg'), dpi=500)
            plt.close('all')

        gc.collect()
```

The following is the C++ code that I used to deploy the model using libtorch:

```
#include <torch/torch.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <torch/script.h>

#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
//#include <opencv2/dnn.hpp>

std::string get_image_type(const cv::Mat& img, bool more_info = true)
{
    std::string r;
    int type = img.type();
    uchar depth = type & CV_MAT_DEPTH_MASK;
    uchar chans = 1 + (type >> CV_CN_SHIFT);

    switch (depth) {
    case CV_8U:  r = "8U"; break;
    case CV_8S:  r = "8S"; break;
    case CV_16U: r = "16U"; break;
    case CV_16S: r = "16S"; break;
    case CV_32S: r = "32S"; break;
    case CV_32F: r = "32F"; break;
    case CV_64F: r = "64F"; break;
    default:     r = "User"; break;
    }

    r += "C";
    r += (chans + '0');

    if (more_info)
        std::cout << "depth: " << img.depth() << " channels: " << img.channels() << std::endl;

    return r;
}

void show_image(cv::Mat& img, std::string title)
{
    std::string image_type = get_image_type(img);
    cv::namedWindow(title + " type:" + image_type, cv::WINDOW_NORMAL); // Create a window for display.
    cv::imshow(title, img);
    cv::waitKey(0);
}

auto transpose(torch::Tensor tensor, c10::IntArrayRef dims = { 0, 3, 1, 2 })
{
    std::cout << "############### transpose ############" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "shape before : " << tensor.sizes() << std::endl;
    tensor = tensor.permute(dims);
    std::cout << "shape after : " << tensor.sizes() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "######################################" << std::endl;
    return tensor;
}

auto ToTensor(cv::Mat img, bool show_output = false, bool unsqueeze = false, int unsqueeze_dim = 0)
{
    std::cout << "image shape: " << img.size() << std::endl;
    torch::Tensor tensor_image = torch::from_blob(img.data, { img.rows, img.cols, 3 }, torch::kByte);

    if (unsqueeze)
    {
        tensor_image.unsqueeze_(unsqueeze_dim);
        std::cout << "tensors new shape: " << tensor_image.sizes() << std::endl;
    }

    if (show_output)
    {
        std::cout << tensor_image.slice(2, 0, 1) << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "tenor shape: " << tensor_image.sizes() << std::endl;
    return tensor_image;
}

auto ToInput(torch::Tensor tensor_image)
{
    // Create a vector of inputs.
    return std::vector<torch::jit::IValue>{tensor_image};
}

auto ToCvImage(torch::Tensor tensor)
{
    int width = tensor.sizes()[0];
    int height = tensor.sizes()[1];
    try
    {
        cv::Mat output_mat(cv::Size{ height, width }, CV_8UC3, tensor.data_ptr<uchar>());

        show_image(output_mat, "converted image from tensor");
        return output_mat.clone();
    }
    catch (const c10::Error& e)
    {
        std::cout << "an error has occured : " << e.msg() << std::endl;
    }
    return cv::Mat(height, width, CV_8UC3);
}

int main() {
  cv::Mat img = cv::imread("D:/Post_Grad/STDF/crack_segmentation-master_original/test_images_mine/00526.jpg");
  cv::Mat img_1;
  cv::resize(img, img_1, cv::Size(448, 448), 0, 0, cv::INTER_AREA);
  
  show_image(img_1, "Test Image");

  // convert the cvimage into tensor
  auto tensor = ToTensor(img_1);

  std::cout << "To Tensor: " << tensor.sizes() << std::endl;

  auto cv_img = ToCvImage(tensor);
  show_image(cv_img, "converted image from tensor");
  
  // swap axis 
  tensor = transpose(tensor, { (2),(0),(1) });

  std::cout << "transpose: " << tensor.sizes() << std::endl;
  
  // convert the tensor into float and scale it 
  tensor = tensor.toType(c10::kFloat).div(255);

  //normalize
  tensor[0] = tensor[0].sub_(0.485).div_(0.229);
  tensor[1] = tensor[1].sub_(0.456).div_(0.224);
  tensor[2] = tensor[2].sub_(0.406).div_(0.225);

  //add batch dim (an inplace operation just like in pytorch)
  tensor.unsqueeze_(0);

  tensor = tensor.to(torch::kCUDA);

  std::cout << "unsqueeze: " << tensor.sizes() << std::endl;

  auto input_to_net = ToInput(tensor);

  torch::jit::script::Module module;

  try
  {
      // Deserialize the ScriptModule from a file using torch::jit::load().
      module = torch::jit::load("D:/Post_Grad/STDF/crack_segmentation-master_original/traced_unet-vgg16_model.pt");

      // Execute the model and turn its output into a tensor.
      torch::Tensor output = module.forward(input_to_net).toTensor();

      //sizes() gives shape. 
      std::cout << output.sizes() << std::endl;
      //std::cout << "output: " << output[0] << std::endl;
      //std::cout << output.slice(/*dim=*/1, /*start=*/0, /*end=*/5) << '\n';
      output = torch::sigmoid(output);
      
      auto out_tensor = output.squeeze(0).detach().permute({ 1, 2, 0 });
      //auto out_tensor = output.squeeze().detach();
      std::cout << "out_tensor (after squeeze & detach): " << out_tensor.sizes() << std::endl;
      out_tensor = out_tensor.mul(255).clamp(0, 255).to(torch::kU8);
      out_tensor = out_tensor.to(torch::kCPU);
      cv::Mat resultImg(448, 448, CV_8UC3);
      std::memcpy((void*)resultImg.data, out_tensor.data_ptr(), sizeof(torch::kU8) * out_tensor.numel());
      cv::resize(resultImg, resultImg, cv::Size(1280, 720), 0, 0, cv::INTER_AREA);

      cv::imwrite("D:/Post_Grad/STDF/crack_segmentation-master_original/test_images_mine/00526-seg-2.jpg", resultImg);
  }
  catch (const c10::Error& e)
  {
      std::cerr << "error loading the model\n" << e.msg();
      std::system("pause");

      return -1;
  }

  std::cout << "ok\n";
  std::system("pause");
  return 0;

  //std::cin.get();
}
```

The output from the original PyTorch model is as follows:
[image]

The output from the libtorch code is as follows:
[image]

It looks similar to the output from PyTorch, but it’s repeated 3 times beside each other.

I failed to discover the reason for this mistake in the above C++. Please, help to check and advise.

Comment: Can you first try to check whether the cause is the NN or the processing ? Take an image, make it an input then an image again and see whether it is duplicated (apply the whole processing pipeline except the segmentation). If no, then the neural network itself has a problem and it will be a more painful debug

Comment: Hi @trialNerror. The images of the tensors after dividing by 255, and after normalizing them aren't showing any duplication. However, I'm wondering how can the neural network has a problem, if it was running correctly in python (PyTorch)? I'm just using the traced module with libtorch.

Comment: I see you're using a three-channel representation for your output image (`CV_8UC3`) Could it be creating one copy of the image for each channel?

Comment: Thank you very much @NickODell. This solved my issue. Pls add your comment as the answer, so that I can mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @MohamedHedeya Sorry, still not totally sure how to solve it, I'm a beginner with OpenCV. But if you self-answer the question and add the code which fixed your problem, I'll upvote it. :)

Comment: @NickODell I just followed your advice, and replaced `CV_8UC3` with `CV_8U`. You gave the correct answer, so pls write it as an answer, so that I can accept it. That's your right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
cv::Mat resultImg(448, 448, CV_8UC3);
```

this declares a matrix with 3 color channels, but you're saving an image with a single channel.

Change it to this:

```
cv::Mat resultImg(448, 448, CV_8U);
```